# While releasing the UIView Object my app is crashing

Tags: iphone, uiview

I developed an iPhone project without XIB files. In that I manually created the UIView object and a few more components on that view also. I release these objects in my `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload` methods. My problem is that if I release the UIView object the app crashes and I do not know why. Can anyone help me in this issue?

Here is my code:

```
allmessengersview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
allmessengersview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.view = allmessengersview;

-(void) dealloc { 
    [allmessengersview release]; 
    [super dealloc]; 
} 

- (void) viewDidUnload { 
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [allmessengersview release]; 
    allmessengersview = nil;
 }
```

Comment: Provide creation and releasing code

Comment: hi this is creation code   
    //creating the view for allmessengers class
    
    allmessengersview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    allmessengersview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view=allmessengersview;  this is dealloc code  -(void)dealloc
{  [allmessengersview release]; [super dealloc]; } and view did unload code  - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload]; [allmessengersview release]; allmessengersview=nil; }

Comment: HI this is the code i am using for that app

Answer (score 0):

Please Write Down this Code in Initialization in View

```
allmessengersview=[[UIView alloc]init];
allmessengersview.frame = CGRect (0,0,320,480);
allmessengersview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
[self.view addsubView: allmessengersview];
```

Please Write Down this Code in Dealloc Methods

```
-(void)dealloc 
{
    [allmessengersview release]; 
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. i already wrote that code in dealloc along with the code of viewdidunload. Small doubt whether we have to release the objects in viewdidunload method or in dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't release in viewDidUnload.
This way the app will release allmessengersview in the viewDidUnload and later on it tries to release it a second time in dealloc, but since it's already released, the app crashes.